# Get notified a vercel build and/or deployment has completed

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am using a deploy hook from my headless CMS (prismic) to kick off a build and deploy on my vercel hosted statically rendered nextJS site. The build time is variable, and I need to run a script after a successful build/deploy, which sends an email and push notifications to my registered users that new content is available. I don't want to do it before the build has finished, otherwise the users will get server side rendered pages instead of static.

I haven't been able to find any way to receive a notification that the build finished. What are my options here?

I do see that I could create a webhook and subscribe to the deployment-ready notification. Does anyone have a working example of this they could share?

- https://vercel.com/docs/api#integrations/webhooks